# How to update a database entry with React and Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I am currently working through React and would like to implement a CRUD API. Except for the update function everything works so far. When I run the update function I get the following error:

*Uncaught (in promise) Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.*

I work with Redux. and Axios.

Edit_Story Component **Updated**:

```
import {editStory } from "../../actions/story";

export class EditStory extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getStory = this.getStory.bind(this);
    this.updateStory = this.updateStory.bind(this);
    this.onChangeTitle = this.onChangeTitle.bind(this);
    this.onChangeContent=this.onChangeContent.bind(this);
    this.onChangeAudio=this.onChangeAudio.bind(this);


this.state = {
    story: {
        id: null,
        title: "",
        content: "",
        audio: ""
      }

    };
}


    componentDidMount() {
    this.getStory(this.props.match.params.id);
  }



  onChangeTitle(e) {
    const title = e.target.value;

    this.setState(function(prevState) {
      return {
        story: {
          ...prevState.story,
          title: title
        }
      };
    });
  }


  onChangeContent(e) {
    const content = e.target.value;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
     story: {
        ...prevState.story,
        content: content
      }
    })); 

  }

  onChangeAudio(e) {
    const audio = e.target.name;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
     story: {
        ...prevState.story,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0]
      }
    }));
  }


  getStory(id) {
    this.props.getSingleStory(id)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          story: response.data
        });
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }  


    updateStory() {
    let story = this.state;
    let formData= new FormData ();
    formData.append('id',story.id);
    formData.append('title',story.title);
    formData.append('content',story.content);
    formData.append('audio',story.audio);
    this.props.editStory(
      formData.id,
      formData
    )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        //this.props.history.push('/story_listview')

      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }


  static propTypes = {
      getSingleStory: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      editStory: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };
```

The  Edit Story action looks like this:

```
// EDIT STORY
export const editStory = (id, data) => (dispatch, getState)=> 
 new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  axios
    .put(apiBase +`/story/${id}/`,data, tokenConfig (getState))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch(createMessage({ editStory: "Story Updated" }));
      dispatch({
        type: EDIT_STORY,
        payload: res.data
      });
      resolve (res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      reject(err);
       dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
     }
     )
});
```

And the Reducer Looks Like this:

```
case EDIT_STORY:
      return {
        ...state,
        story: state.story.filter(story => story.id  !== action.payload)
      };
```

Im not yet realy familiar with redux and do not find the error.

Thanks for every hint.

**EDIT**

It appears that somehow the data passed to the action `.put(apiBase +/story/${id}/,data, tokenConfig (getState))` is added to the `apiBase +` and ends up in the path. So the path to a story finally looks like `http://localhost:3000/?title=dfdf_BLABA&content=dfdf#/story/9`. I guess that could be the reason why there is no connection possible.

Why does the update function write the data into the path and how to fix that?

Comment: check your server if it is running. Then also check the url that is used here `.put(apiBase +'/story/${id}'/`. If it is correct.

Comment: This doesn't look like a redux or react issue. You are getting an error saying your react app can't connect to the requested url

Comment: You might try to send a postmen request to this API to ensure that it's work.

Comment: Somehow the data passed to the action `.put(apiBase +`/story/${id}/`,data, tokenConfig (getState))` is added to the `apiBase +` and  ends up in the path. So the path to a story finally looks like `http://localhost:3000/?title=dfdf_BLABA&content=dfdf#/story/9`. Why does the update function write the data into the path?

Comment: Are you sure that you set the right content type in the request? I mean `{ headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} }`

Comment: @OlehDrozd I tried your advice and if i check the API with postmen I can successfully update the story. However when I try it via the react front end it doesnt work. I use form data to communicate with my backend. I updated in the orginal post the component as well as the action to give more details about the problem. I'm happy for every help.

Comment: Man, you should have used FormData only to send files 'cause the browser handles it a bit different than other request types. Instead to send simple objects you have to use plain request (without formData). Just try to pass a plain object with data in `.put()` method and check out 'network' tab in dev-tools to see what happens.